# DAC: Vcc or Vref determine resolution?

Tags: dac, resolution, vcc

Does the resolution of a DAC depend on the supply voltage or on the reference voltage? How would the possible voltage levels be calculated if we have, for example, a DAC with Vcc = 5V, Vref = 0.5V and resolution of 8bit?

Comment: Pick a DAC and add the datasheet link to the question and explain what part of the datasheet you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Resolution for ADC/DAC could be estimated by LSB (Least Significant Bit) i.e given by:

$$ LSB = \frac{V_{ref}}{2^N} $$, where \$ N \$ is number of bits. But these are for architectures that use voltage for conversion, there are architectures that use current then this may not hold true.

Answer (score 0):

Vref would be used. An N-bit DAC has 2^N possible levels of binary input. Hence resolution would be  (Vref/2^N -1). For high values of N, we usually approximate it to Vref/2^N for ease.

To convert any digital input to its corresponding analog voltage level, just convert the binary of the input to corresponding decimal notation and multiply it with the resolution.